# "Not enough permissions to access: GET-members /emailAddress" - C#, RestSharp, Postman, LinkedIn API

Tags: c#, .net, linkedin-api, restsharp

I'm attempting to access the LinkedIn API's so I can post some text to a page via c# but I'm running into the titled error when attempting to retrieve the user handle.

I've followed the guides that have me set up an application, verify that application, get the auth code (approved), get an access token, and now I"m stuck on retrieving the handle.

I've tried using both the liteprofile and the basic profile. Whenever I attempt to use the liteprofile I get the "unauthorized_scope_error" message in my redirect url. When I use the basicprofile I get the authorization code but then run into the permission error.

I've also been reading about how liteprofile is the profile that "should" be used right now but that it also has its disadvantages.

I'll try to add some code while also removing some of the personal stuff (the removed code will be in {}).

Here's my Postman GET that gives me a successful redirect and auth code:

```
    GET https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri=https://www.linkedin.com/company/{removed}/admin/&state=fooobar&scope=r_basicprofile%20r_emailaddress%20
```

Here's my POST (using the auth code from the previous GET) to retrieve my access token:

```
    POST https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code={code}&redirect_uri={redirect_url}&client_id={client_id}&client_secret={client_secret}
```

Here's my Postman GET that should be giving me the handle but instead is returning the error:

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))&oauth2_access_token={access_token}
```

And the error:

```
{
"serviceErrorCode": 100,
"message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET-members /emailAddress",
"status": 403
}
```

I would like to get the handle for the linked in page but instead I'm receiving the titled error message in the response body.

Comment: Scope errors occur when you haven't got the required rights do do what it is you do

Comment: ... next to that, it would help to post code here. If it's full with personal info: you should remove it either way

Comment: Updated with the code that I could use and removing the personal info. Let me know what else you would need to see.

Answer (score 0):

Issue with oAuth 2.0 LinkedIn Upgrade API Web Service it Seems.

Please refer this

https://github.com/laravel/socialite/pull/310